# Animation with Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I want to make text animation on my website using `css3` and `javascript`.

Here is what i want:

There is text which is going from right to left see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jw0h65m5/).

It is working, but it does not work on my page. I do not know why.

Here is web site:

http://rmb-elektro.eu/index.php/sk/o-nas

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdMgD.png

Comment: if you dont mind, can you also add the JS, it might not be library issue but issue with your code

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your site `$(...).appear is not a function` you forgot to include jquery or other required libraries.

[image: Error]